Delete Multiple MS Teams
I have a PHP script that is dynamically creating Teams whenever we start a new project.
During the testing phase hundreds of 'test' Teams were created and I'm trying to find a way of deleting all these permanently.
Is there an easy way to do this or any way to delete these that is similar to deleting folders in Explorer?

Not like Explorer, because they aren't at all the same thing. Teams are Microsoft 365 Groups. You can delete Microsoft 365 Groups easily enough, including in a form of bulk, using Entra or PowerShell.

I did realise that (or I wouldn't be able to generate them automatically), but I'm trying to find a way that isn't too hard to delete. A powershell script to delete all before a certain date would work. Any idea how to do that, please?

You might be able to use Remove-Team to remove the group.

What research have you done and what have you tried? Get-Team probably provides a DateCreated value of some sort, and piping in PS is quite simple as well. The thing is, this question is about admin-level computer work and not specifically about a computers within the bounds defined in the Help section. It may be on topic on SuperUser, except the question will not be well received there in its current form due to it not showing anything that OP has yet tried, research they have done, etc. Show something you've tried, show the research you've done, show how it has not worked as you want.

@TomC ... Might be time to test and work it all out via MS Graph commands (or api)....  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.teams/new-mgteam?view=graph-powershell-1.0, or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.teams/copy-mgteam?view=graph-powershell-1.0, or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.teams/remove-mgteam?view=graph-powershell-1.0 to help with this somewhat automated fashion when you hit the trigger to do the action. Works well for me. Further pointers available, just ping me.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle the Graph API interfaces, while no doubt comprehensive, look significantly more complex than the likes of New-Team, Get-Team, and Remove-Team

@ChrisDavies It may be more comprehensive to understand initially perhaps, but it's what I call more modern command wise for M365 cloud resources, but the Get-Team, New-Team, etc. will work too and I do also use for for similar operations too. Until something is deprecated and advised to not use, we have options luckily enough at the moment. Here's an example post what the commands for cloning looks like, really simple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78115047/error-cloning-microsoft-teams-group-with-powershell/... Examples all over the Internet otherwise.

You can list the Teams from Powershell using the Get-Team command. Unfortunately it doesn't provide a "Created" date. However, you can filter the corresponding Microsoft 365 Groups by age via Exchange Online. So here, what we need to do is to join the Teams records with the Groups records so that we can pick out the Teams by date.
First,
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams

Then connect (to both) using suitable Microsoft 365 credentials
Connect-ExchangeOnline
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

Now you can query the list of Teams and filter them by name, date, etc. This example filters by name containing "Test":
Get-Team |
    Where { $_.DisplayName -like "*Test*" } |
    ForEach-Object { Remove-Team -GroupId $_.GroupId }

And this example deletes all Teams that were created on or after 1st April 2024:
Get-Team |
    ForEach-Object {
        @{
            WhenCreated = (Get-Group -Id $_.GroupId).WhenCreated
            GroupId = $_.GroupId
            DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
        }
    } |
    Where { $_.WhenCreated -ge (Get-Date "2024-04-01") } |
    ForEach-Object { Remove-Team -GroupId $_.GroupId }

You can of course slap Write-Host in front of either of the Remove-Team commands to see what would happen.
(Readable improvements to the code happily accepted, as would useful error handling.)
References

Get-Team
Get-Group
Managing Microsoft Teams using PowerShell

